# jQuery validation required condition using checkboxes

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using a HTML form where the overall behavior is controlled by a checkbox `name="doregister"`

> (unchecked = login, checked = register)

The visibility of the fields is controlled by this checkbox. Registration fields are supposed to be validated:

I am trying to controle validation in the following way:

```
jQuery("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        loginusername: {
            required:  function() { return jQuery("input[name=doregister]").is(":checked")?"1":"0"=="0";},
        },
        ...
        salutation: {
            required:  function() { return jQuery("input[name=doregister]").is(":checked")?"1":"0"=="1";},
        },
        ...
});
```

This failed for the checked checkbox doregister, i.e. salutation is not validated.

Any hints?

Comment: Why `"0"=="1"`? That's a weird condition. Why not simply using `false`?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1eth1ycs/2/

Comment: You are perfectly right. It's a manner of missing paratheses.

Comment: but if the elements are hidden there is no need to do it - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1eth1ycs/3/ - because by default hidden elements are not validated

Comment: Ok, hidding is a generalisation for graying out form elements and set them readonly. The logical overhead is due to "next level programming".

Answer (score 0):

Your condition inside your function does NOT return a boolean properly.

```
return jQuery("input[name=doregister]").is(":checked")?"1":"0"=="1";
```

When it is checked, it returns the STRING "1" which is NOT a boolean and in this case does not get type conversion either as it does not know to do so, thus your condition fails to be "required".

You COULD fix your really odd conditional by forcing a boolean as follows:

```
return jQuery("input[name=doregister]").is(":checked")?!!"1":"0"=="1";
```

DO NOT DO THAT, simply return the boolean value of the checkbox state instead:

```
return jQuery("input[name='doregister']")[0].checked;
```

Note that the OTHER one should be "NOT" of that check state: using `!`

```
return !jQuery("input[name='doregister']")[0].checked;
```

Code segment:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
      loginusername: {
        required: function () {
          return !jQuery("input[name='doregister']")[0].checked;
        },
      },
      salutation: {
        required: function () {
          return jQuery("input[name='doregister']")[0].checked;
        },
      }
    }
  });
```